# new variable by subtracting rows based on condition in grouped data

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I have data for every census tract in the country at three time points (2000, 2013, 2019) that is grouped by CBSA. I'm trying to create a new variable called cont_chg_pedu_colplus that is the difference between the 2013 and 2000 value for pedu_colplus. So, in my example below, I want to create a new column called cont_chg_pedu_colplus that returns the value of 3.0 (14.6 - 11.6). Ideally, each group of tracts would have the same value, since I'm only interested in the difference between time 1 and time 2.

```
  tractid      year CBSA_name   pedu_colplus
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>
1 48059030101  2000 Abilene, TX         11.6
2 48059030101  2013 Abilene, TX         14.6
3 48059030101  2019 Abilene, TX         20.6
4 48059030102  2000 Abilene, TX         11.6
5 48059030102  2013 Abilene, TX         14.2
6 48059030102  2019 Abilene, TX         20.2
```

Below is the code I have so far. It throws the following error, I think because I'm subsetting on just one year (37 rows instead of the 111 in the dataset). I'd prefer not to make my data wide, because I've got a bunch of other data manipulations I have to. I couldn't get lag to work.

```
gent_vars_prelim <- outcome_data %>% 
    
  mutate(cont_chg_pedu_colplus = pedu_colplus[year == 2013] - pedu_colplus[year == 2000], na.rm = TRUE) %>%
                
  glimpse()
```

> Problem with `mutate()` input `cont_chg_pedu_colplus`. x Input `cont_chg_pedu_colplus` can't be recycled to size 37. ℹ Input `cont_chg_pedu_colplus` is `pedu_colplus[year == 2013] - pedu_colplus[year == 2000]`. ℹ Input `cont_chg_pedu_colplus` must be size 37 or 1, not 0. ℹ The error occurred in group 1: CBSA_name = "Abilene, TX", year = 2000

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: I think you could do `outcome_data %>% dplyr::group_by(tractid) %>% dplyr::mutate(., cont_chg_pedu_colplus = dplyr::filter(., year == 2013)$pedu_colplus - dplyr::filter(., year == 2000)$pedu_colplus) %>% dplyr::ungroup()`. But maybe there's a simpler approach?

Comment: Thanks @Dillon! It works on my example, which is just one metro area but when I try to run it on the entire dataset that has all the CBSAs, it throws the same error. Could I use the experimental `split_by` and split each CBSA into its own data frame?https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_split.html

Comment: Oh right, you'd probably need to also group by CBSA_name. So the grouping would look like `dplyr::group_by(tractid, CBSA_name)`.

Comment: @Dillon, I get the same error as in my original post, but "Input `cont_chg_pedu_colplus` can't be recycled to size 3" instead of 37.

Comment: I think it's a problem with my use of `filter`. Try using my `group_by` but with your original method of `pedu_colplus[year == 20xx]`. The following appears to work for me: `gent_vars_prelim <- outcome_data %>% dplyr::group_by(tractid, CBSA_name) %>% dplyr::mutate(cont_chg_pedu_colplus = pedu_colplus[year == 2013] - pedu_colplus[year == 2000]) %>% dplyr::ungroup() %>% glimpse()`.

Comment: I noticed your `CBSA_name` is type `<chr>` instead of `<fct>`. You might need to convert the `CBSA_name` column to a factor with `outcome_data$CBSA_name <- as.factor(outcome_data$CBSA_name)` so that it groups properly.

Comment: @Dillon, that didn't work, but I think its because each year has a different number of tracts in at least one CBSA. For example in Tuscon, AZ, the year 2000 has 239 tracts, whereas 2013 and 2019 have 232. I can't quite figure out why that is because I used the following command to even them out and I thought it worked   `complete(tractid, year = c(2000, 2013, 2019))`

Comment: One possible solution to the problem of mis-matched counts of tracts (assuming there is a unique pair of `tractid` and `CBSA_name` for every group of 3 years), is to call `dplyr::filter(n() == 3)` between the calls to `group_by` and `mutate`. This way, only the groups with all 3 years are kept. But this would discard the incomplete groups in the result, which may not be desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that for each unique pair of `tractid` and `CBSA_name`, there are up to 3 entries for `year` (possible values 2000, 2013, or 2019) and no two years are the same for a given pair of `tractid` and `CBSA_name`.

First, we'll group the values in the data frame by `tractid` and `CBSA_name`. Each group will have up to 3 rows, one for each year. We do this with `dplyr::group_by(tractid, CBSA_name)`.

Next, we'll force the group to have all 3 years. We do this with `tidyr::complete(year = c(2000, 2013, 2019))` as you suggested in the comments. (This is better than my comment using `filter(n() == 3)`, because we actually wouldn't care if only 2019 were missing, and we are able to preserve incomplete groups.)

Then, we can compute the result you're interested in: `dplyr::mutate(cont_chg_pedu_colplus = pedu_colplus[year == 2013] - pedu_colplus[year == 2000])`. We just need to `dplyr::ungroup()` after this and we're done.

Final code:

```
gent_vars_prelim <- outcome_data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(tractid, CBSA_name) %>%
  tidyr::complete(year = c(2000, 2013, 2019)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(cont_chg_pedu_colplus = pedu_colplus[year == 2013] - pedu_colplus[year == 2000]) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  glimpse()
```

Test case:

```
outcome_data <- data.frame(tractid = c(48059030101, 48059030101, 48059030101, 48059030101, 48059030101, 48059030101, 48059030102, 48059030102, 48059030102, 48059030103),
                           year = c(2000, 2013, 2019, 2000, 2013, 2019, 2000, 2013, 2019, 2000),
                           CBSA_name = c("Abilene, TX", "Abilene, TX", "Abilene, TX", "Austin, TX", "Austin, TX", "Austin, TX", "Abilene, TX", "Abilene, TX", "Abilene, TX", "Abilene, TX"),
                           pedu_colplus = c(11.6, 14.6, 20.6, 8.4, 9.0, 9.6, 11.6, 14.2, 20.2, 4.0))
```

Result:

```
> tibble(gent_vars_prelim)
# A tibble: 12 x 1
   gent_vars_prelim$tractid $CBSA_name  $year $pedu_colplus $cont_chg_pedu_colplus
                      <dbl> <fct>       <dbl>         <dbl>                  <dbl>
 1              48059030101 Abilene, TX  2000          11.6                  3    
 2              48059030101 Abilene, TX  2013          14.6                  3    
 3              48059030101 Abilene, TX  2019          20.6                  3    
 4              48059030101 Austin, TX   2000           8.4                  0.600
 5              48059030101 Austin, TX   2013           9                    0.600
 6              48059030101 Austin, TX   2019           9.6                  0.600
 7              48059030102 Abilene, TX  2000          11.6                  2.60 
 8              48059030102 Abilene, TX  2013          14.2                  2.60 
 9              48059030102 Abilene, TX  2019          20.2                  2.60 
10              48059030103 Abilene, TX  2000           4                   NA    
11              48059030103 Abilene, TX  2013          NA                   NA    
12              48059030103 Abilene, TX  2019          NA                   NA
```

Comment: thanks this worked. I think the key was using the correct `complete` command and adjusting the grouping structure correctly. Thanks for your help on this, really appreciate it!